# submit form, stay on same page and message confirmation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form, and when I submit it, it goes to another page.
To fix this, I left empty the action field in the html. But now, the php doesn't send the mail.
I want to stay on same page, send the mail and get a message confirmation. 
I have not so much knowledge about this, and I can't fix it by myself.
Here is the code:

```
  <form id="idForm"method="post" action="">
                    <div class="row 50%">
                        <div class="6u 12u$(mobile)"><input id="nome" required="required" type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Nome" /></div>
                        <div class="6u$ 12u$(mobile)"><input id="email" required="required" type="email" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" /></div>
                        <div class="12u$">
                            <textarea id="mensaxe" required="required" name="mensaxe" placeholder="Mensaxe"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="12u$">
                            <ul class="actions">
                                <li><input type="submit" value="Enviar mensaxe" />
                                 <span id="message"></span>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and here the php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// Debes editar las próximas dos líneas de código de acuerdo con tus preferencias
$email_to = "info@mymail.es";
$email_subject = "Contacto desde el sitio web";

// Aquí se deberían validar los datos ingresados por el usuario
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['mensaxe'])) {

echo "<b>Ocurrió un error y el formulario no ha sido enviado. </b><br />";
echo "Por favor, vuelva atrás y verifique la información ingresada<br />";
die();
}

$email_message = "Detalles del formulario de contacto:\n\n";
$email_message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$email_message .= "Comentarios: " . $_POST['mensaxe'] . "\n\n";


// Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);


}
?>
```

And the js

```
   $("#idForm").submit(function() {
  event.preventDefault();

    var url = "../php/formulario.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
              $("message").text("Success Message");
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

I appreciate any help!! Thanks.

Comment: On your script just use `header('Location: url');` to get back to the page. Alternatively just include the script on the same page and use ajax to post to that same page

Comment: event.preventDefault should do what you need, but in your js it doesn't look like you've passed in the event, try doing $('#idForm').submit(function(event) { .....

Comment: You are also missing a `#` in your jQuery. Should be `$('#message').text(...)`

Answer (score 2):

event is missing in the function parameter

```
$("#idForm").submit(function(event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

in your js, you must change like this:

```
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

for not send by post the form in the same page (action empty = same page )

And in your ajax, you have a mistake:

```
$("message").text("Success Message");
$("#message").text("Success Message"); //CORRECT with #
```

you can change function(data) for function(html) and make an alert(html) for see what the php page say .. ;)